# Visit all cells in rectangular grid in a zigzag manner

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, geometry

Given a rectangular grid and a point, I need an algorithm for visiting all points in a zigzag manner.

So, I'm looking for a function **f** that generates the below plot if run like this:

```
loop:
    new_x, new_y = f(x, y, minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
    if new_x == x and new_y == y:
        end loop
```

[image]

Can someone help me with such an algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be warned, I count from 1:

1. If you are on an odd-numbered row step to the right.
2. If you are on an even-numbered row step to the left.
3. If you are at the end of a row step up.

This is a bit fiddly to code but I can't see any particular problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 0<=X<=L, and 0<=Y, given an index N, you can find the coordinates as follows:

Y = floor(N/L)

X = (Y is even)? N mod L : L - (N mod L) - 1

--Edit--

I Notice that this doesn't comply with your loop structure constraint, but it may be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<size_t, size_t>
foo (size_t N, size_t k) {
    const auto r = k / N;
    const auto c = (r & 1) == 0 ? k % N  : N - k % N - 1;
    return {r, c};
}

int
main () {
    const size_t N = 10;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N * N; ++i) {
        auto p = foo (N, i);
        std::cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```